# "Check if you haven't" or "check if you have" left anything behind?

Tags: grammar, negation, speech, linguistics

This might be trivial but it didn't sound right to me when I thought about it, so I decided to ask.

An automated message I've heard says "please check if you haven't left anything behind". It sounded funny to me because it gave me the impression as if they meant "you should leave something behind" if taken literally, or "if you haven't left anything behind, do leave something"

Obviously this isn't what they MEANT, and the point is understandable, but I'm asking if it's a misuse and if they should've said "please check if you have left anything behind"

Or does it not matter either way?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a native English expression.  It would more likely be something like "Please verify that you haven't left anything behind" or "Please check to see if you have left anything behind".  Would that make more sense?